# Diffusion equation in sphere with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I  have the  diffusion equation in a sphere of radius R given by:

$$\frac{\partial U(r,t)}{\partial t} = D\left[\frac{\partial^2 U(r,t)}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial U(r,t)}{\partial r}\right]$$

$D$ is a constant greater than $1$, with boundary conditions:

$$\begin{array}
UU(r,0)&=\frac{4}{r}\sin^3 \left(\frac{\pi r}{R }\right) \\
U(R,t)&=0
\end{array}$$

and $|U (0,t)|$ is finite for all $t$.

Using separation of variables I  have:

$$U=T(t)R(r)$$

with

$$T=c\exp(pDt)$$

where $c$ is a constant, and

$$R=A \frac{\sin ((\sqrt p)r)}{r}+B\frac{\cos((\sqrt p)r)}{r}$$
with $A$ and $B$ as constants.

I'm now confused how to implement the boundary conditions,normally I just get $B$  to be $0$ but this time I have a different boundary condition dealing with the boundary,so I'm missing the eigenvalue equation I normally have.

I think after that I can use the formula for $\sin 3r$ to compare coefficients in the infinite sum to find my solution but how do I get the $\frac{\pi }{R}$ in my infinite sum?

.

Comment: I can write $R(r)=\frac{A'}{r}sin(\sqrt (p) r+\phi)$ and then U(R,t)=0 gives me $sin(\sqrt(p)R+\phi)$=0 so $\sqrt(p)R+\phi=k\pi$ so i really want to get rid of $\phi$

Comment: Just an idea but what if you write your solution as : $Ae^{p_1Dt}sin(\sqrt p_1r)/r +Be^{p_2Dt}sin(\sqrt p_2r)/r  $ and find $p_1$ and $p_2$ from the decomposition of $sin^3(x)$ in $sin(x)$ and $sin(3x)$

Comment: also I think you should have $exp(-Dp^2t)sin(pr) $ as solution since the solution of $y'(t)+p^2y(t)=0$ is $e^{-p^2t}$

Comment: Then once you have $p_1$ and $p_2$ and $A$ and $B$ you can check it is indeed solution of your Cauchy problem and since it must be the only you have solved your problem. The minus in the exponential makes sense as your final state is $U(r,\infty)=0$ since you have a Dirichlet boundary condition of $0$. Therefore at $t\rightarrow\infty$ all the heat should have been dissipated out of your sphere